# Where is "mkpasswd" for OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

There is a well-known unix utility called [`mkpasswd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkpasswd) available on many *nix systems.

I was just trying to use it from terminal on an OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite (Early 2015) machine, and it is nowhere to be found.

How can I install it on this machine? or is there an alternative already available?

Comment: And FWIW, there is an interesting [online password generator](https://www.memset.com/tools/password-generator/) I've found which lacks options, but looks useful all the same!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a Mac implementation of mkpasswd on GitHub - https://github.com/PrototypeAlex/mkpasswd

Alternatively, Keychain Access has a built-in GUI password generator
File menu > New Password Item... > [click the key icon]

*drop-menu artificially offset for visibility*

[image]

I also found this [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2303658?start=0&tstart=0) on how to achieve it natively, though it's unfortunately above my skill-level, so I'll let you see if you think it might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks - the "Mac implementation" is a ruby script requiring "gems" -- any idea what it's relationship is to the unix `mkpasswd.c` utility? Helpful Apple Discussion thread: my main take-away is that you can use `$ slappasswd -g` from the command line natively in OSX to generate an 8-character mixed case + digits password, but no way to tailor output (e.g. string length) that I can see, like there is with the Keychain Access helper.

Comment: Sorry, idk what the relationship may be - I'm afraid my skill-set is very much GUI-based, so I always rely on the Keychain version.

Comment: https://github.com/PrototypeAlex/mkpasswd is dead

Comment: yes this answer is a bit outdated. check my answer below with golang multi platform implementation. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407318/68672

Comment: @David, you could do something like `for i in {0..$(($n/8))}; do slappasswd -g; done | tr '\n' '' | head -c $n`, where `$n` is the desired password length. Stick that in a script in your `$PATH` called `mkpasswd` with `n=$1`, and then you can do e.g. `mkpasswd 22` to get a 22-character password.

Answer (score 10):

Coming from the [docker](https://www.docker.com/) world, on your Mac/Windows/Linux box (with docker installed):

```bsh
docker run -it --rm alpine mkpasswd -m des helloworld
```

Replace your `mkpasswd` arguments as needed.

Comment: absolutely great idea. My example:
docker run -it --rm alpine sh -c 'printf "P@$$w0rD" | mkpasswd -s -m md5'

Answer (score 9):

I made a tool for creating `mkpasswd -m sha-512` (Linux/Ubuntu) style hashes on OS X (or any platform).

First, we need to acquire a single requirement...

```
pip3 install passlib
```

Now we create mkpasswd_sha-512.py (or whatever you want to call it)...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17992126/117471

import sys
from getpass import getpass
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt

passwd = input() if not sys.stdin.isatty() else getpass()
print(sha512_crypt.hash(passwd))
```

It only handles a single use case of `mkpasswd` but if it fits, enjoy.

**Note:** There is a slightly more complicated version at https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/58f1b34d2bcf4c4e5f1cd18a88fdc37d which simplifies tuning the CPU Cost, but [passlib manages that periodically for you](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/narr/hash-tutorial.html#choosing-the-right-rounds-value) so it's fine to keep it simple like this.

Comment: Great answer, this works perfectly for me after I ran `pip3 install passlib`

Comment: @WillSheppard thank you! I added that detail to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/expect/expect-1/expect/example/mkpasswd?txt) for `mkpasswd`. It's an `expect` script. You would have to modify the script (at least the shebang) in order for it to work. There are other command line tools such as `openssl` (`md5`), `jot` and `dd` that can generate passwords.

Comment: `pwgen` is also useful and has similar options to `mkpasswd` for phonetic/memorable passwords . I was not familiar with mkpasswd and found this comparison: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/generating-random-password/

Comment: `jot` is a new one for me (from BSD?) and included with OSX. There's a nice [forum post](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=2912#post21666) giving examples of its use for password generation.

Answer (score 2):

## With `openssl`

In macOS, it's very simple, using `openssl` which is a native already installed package (as mentioned in [the apple article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2303658) shared in @Tetsujin’s answer):

I'm going here to explain how to use in details:

```bash
openssl passwd -6
```

- 6 stands for SHA-512

To show what crypto hashes are supported:

```bash
openssl passed -help
```

- Check `Cryptographic options:`

```
Input options:
 -in infile          Read passwords from file
 -noverify           Never verify when reading password from terminal
 -stdin              Read passwords from stdin

Output options:
 -quiet              No warnings
 -table              Format output as table
 -reverse            Switch table columns

Cryptographic options:
 -salt val           Use provided salt
 -6                  SHA512-based password algorithm
 -5                  SHA256-based password algorithm
 -apr1               MD5-based password algorithm, Apache variant
 -1                  MD5-based password algorithm
 -aixmd5             AIX MD5-based password algorithm

Random state options:
 -rand val           Load the given file(s) into the random number generator
 -writerand outfile  Write random data to the specified file

Provider options:
 -provider-path val  Provider load path (must be before 'provider' argument if required)
 -provider val       Provider to load (can be specified multiple times)
 -propquery val      Property query used when fetching algorithms
```

## Using python

### Refs

- [Automate Server Configuration with Ansible Playbooks](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/running-ansible-playbooks/)

  - usage with `ansible playbook` example (I took that one-liner and adapted it for Python3 and used `getpass()`)
- [passlib.hash.sha512_crypt - SHA-512 Crypt](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.html)

### Execution

One-liner:

```bash
python3 -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass; swd = getpass.getpass('Password:'); print(sha512_crypt.hash(swd))"
```

output format

```
$6$rounds=656000$9NGDC8UzAGWWIdNP$Xltp2/G/Q6geYDe07q2l426oV7b.nqjPpc7t6GZVbdZwM7XQrCDdwNkUCBvjGMZmj9qnbZ.tkmnXlxN04YY.s.
```

- Note that the output from this differs from the one of OpenSSL. It should work in things like `ansible`, and I suppose other usages. Because if the OS supports `crypt()` then `passlib` will use that `sys call`. There is a round param and others, check the reference above.

### Requirements

- Install the `passlib` library:

```
pip3 install --user passlib
```

## `slappasswd` no SHA512

- `slappasswd` doesn't support `SHA512`

  - [slappasswd(8) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/slappasswd)

`man slappasswd`

```
-h "scheme"
       If -h is specified, one of the following RFC 2307 schemes may be specified: {CRYPT}, {MD5}, {SMD5}, {SSHA},
       and {SHA}.  The default is {SSHA}.

       Note that scheme names may need to be protected, due to { and }, from expansion by the user's command
       interpreter.

       {SHA} and {SSHA} use the SHA-1 algorithm (FIPS 160-1), the latter with a seed.

       {MD5} and {SMD5} use the MD5 algorithm (RFC 1321), the latter with a seed.

       {CRYPT} uses the crypt(3).

       {CLEARTEXT} indicates that the new password should be added to userPassword as clear text.  Unless
       {CLEARTEXT} is used, this flag is incompatible with option -g.
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. It is not searchable and is inaccessible to those with visual disabilities. Please [edit] your answer to include actual text.

Comment: @argaza for the images that i set. I don't think they matter from a search point. All info that matters was included as text. Including the help for `openssl passwd` which i included as text. For the slappaswd the images were just to illustrate the command line, i included the man command. Also i included a link to the doc online as well. I'm already familiar with the image concern. And i tend to always respect it. Thank you a lot. And feel free to review my statement and if anything I'll handle it.

Comment: Please note the following Meta post: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: This answer is the best answer, even if they are using photos. This is a native way to get the mkpasswd output, from a bulit-in mac binary.

Comment: @agarza thank you for the shared link. And i agree with most of what it says. Text does provide for the users with visual impairments. And some optimization for phone. For all; statement about code. They don't apply in my case. All images shared here have one role. Illustrating, that you can check using the cli. And that's what the output look like. As text does provide. The images as well does provide what text doesn't. Including the native good formating. Or showing the context. Which remove confusion and illustrate better. I used 4 images total. For the two first code was provided.

Comment: For the two first the code is added. I did update and added the python output format in text now. The last two images are about `slappasswd` and i included a link to doc online, and also the command to show the man doc. The image illustrate that. Now after your suggestions i did add the doc as a text as well. I like to keep the images for this reasons. My images are not about code. Or anything meant to copy. Only illustration of terminal usage. Benefit: - credibility, memory, showing doing it. The only drawback is the image size. Which i don't see a valid point in the modern time.

Comment: I've removed the screenshots as they didn't add any value in addition to the answer provided. Also, for visually impaired users it's still confusing because they have no way to understand that they don't miss out on anything in the pictures. There is no need to *show* that it works within the answer, users here assume that you tested your code anyway before posting :-)

Comment: @nohillside Thank you +1. I see the community here is strict about this. I have no issue in StackOverflow. i edited slightly what you did. Some formatting and important highlights. like python is python3. I see it important.
- For the help as well i did re-include it fully. And pointed to the section to check. So people can check the help on there way

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. Python3 actually was still in :-)

Comment: Thank you again. And for python3 yea. And I kept what you added. However, people tend to not pay attention. So I added the note to make it simple for them in case of Python issues.

Comment: There is no Python 2 on macOS anyway, so the risk of getting this wrong is rather small. Actually, there isn't even a `python` binary, it's called `python3` (and `pip3`).

Comment: Thank you again, I guess being implicit with `pip3` and `python3` can remove the confusion. In my setup, I'm using `pyenv` to manage `python versions`. And I do have `python` command. The brew version also does set the `python` alias or command (https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/). Other people set the alias themselves.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/myENA/mkpasswd) is a simple mkpasswd utility written in golang for platform portability.

```
mkpasswd -h

Usage of mkpasswd:
  -hash string
        Optional hash argument: sha512, sha256, md5 or apr1 (default "sha512")
  -password string
        Optional password argument
  -rounds int
        Optional number of rounds
  -salt string
        Optional salt argument without prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed `mkpasswd` on my macOS Catalina (10.15.2) using `sudo gem install mkpasswd`

Comment: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unix-crypt-1.3.0/lib/unix_crypt/base.rb:5:in `build': Salts longer than 2 characters are not permitted (UnixCrypt::SaltTooLongError)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the original `mkpasswd` utility, just install `expect` using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

`brew install expect`

However, the original `mkpasswd` does not include the capability to hash a password using SHA-512 mentioned elsewhere on this page.

Another way to get that is to [install](https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/using-cpan-to-extend-perl-on-mac-os-x#installing-cpan-modules-on-your-mac) the Perl CPAN distributions [App::bmkpasswd](https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/using-cpan-to-extend-perl-on-mac-os-x#installing-cpan-modules-on-your-mac) (providing `bmkpasswd`) and [Crypt::Passwd::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::bmkpasswd) (providing SHA support).

You can then run:

`bmkpasswd --method='sha512' <password>`

on the command line to hash a password (specified in place of `<password>`) using SHA-512.

Answer (score -1):

I successfully installed `mkpasswd` on my macOS 10.14.5 using `gem install mkpasswd`.

```
gem install mkpasswd
Fetching mkpasswd-0.1.0.gem
Fetching unix-crypt-1.3.0.gem
Successfully installed unix-crypt-1.3.0
Successfully installed mkpasswd-0.1.0
Parsing documentation for unix-crypt-1.3.0
Installing ri documentation for unix-crypt-1.3.0
Parsing documentation for mkpasswd-0.1.0
Installing ri documentation for mkpasswd-0.1.0
Done installing documentation for unix-crypt, mkpasswd after 0 seconds
2 gems installed
```

[Here](https://serversforhackers.com/c/create-user-in-ansible) is where I get this information.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/unix-crypt-1.3.0/lib/unix_crypt/base.rb:5:in `build': Salts longer than 2 characters are not permitted (UnixCrypt::SaltTooLongError)